# Get file, source line and variable name in signal handler

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, g++, signals

I installed custom signal handler for segfaults

```
void sa_sigHandler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
  ...
  void *variableAddr = info->si_addr;
  ucontext_t *uctx = (ucontext_t *)context;    
  unsigned long inst = uctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP];
  // how to get file, source line and object name here ?
  ...
}
```

I saw a few similar questions but found no concrete code to achieve this.

Comment: You're going to have to load and parse debugging information out of the executable. This is difficult, poorly documented, and unsafe to attempt from inside a signal handler. Also, you're reinventing the wheel. Have a look at [Breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/) and [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

Comment: Which variable name are you looking for?

Comment: In my case, its the address(of shared object) on which segfault occurs

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have .cpp files

Comment: @zwol I am building a tool wherein I need this information for better reporting.

Comment: @ruke but you had tagged the question with C. I see that you've changed that now. Good

Answer (score 0):

> Get file, source line and variable name in signal handler

As @zwol commented, this is pretty hard to do, and you'll be better off using existing solutions, such as [Breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/) or [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

If you must report this at runtime, you may be better off wrapping the application in a GDB script; something like `gdb -ex run -ex where -ex quit /path/to/a.out`.

If you still insist on doing this in `C` or `C++`, you could benefit from [libdwarf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/), but note that using it from a signal handler presents additional complications (it is not async-signal safe), so you'll need to build a map from program counters to source file/line info *ahead of time*, and only do the lookups at crash time.

> in my case, I am looking for the address(of shared object) on which segfault occurs

The *address* which caused `SIGSEGV` is directly available as `uctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]` and your code already gets that as `inst`, so you are not looking for that, but for something else.

If that something else is "file / line info for the above address", see above. You could also `execv` this command to print that info (this can be done in async-safe manner): `/usr/bin/addr2line -fe /path/to/binary $inst`.